# Java FileReader: How to assign every line in the text file to a variable

Tags: java, file, filereader

I want every line in my textdoc to be assigned to a variable.

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

class readfile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename");
            BufferedReader br = new Buffered(fr);
            String str;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {}
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("file not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest instead of assigning every line to a variable, you can create a list and store every line into the list. Later you can retrieve line string from the list when need them line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create a List and store every line in a list like below:

```
 String str;
 List<String> fileText = ....;
 while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
     fileText.add(str);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java 8 solution for creating a List of lines

```
 Path path = Paths.get("filename");
 List<String> lines = Files.lines(path).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
 List<string> allText= new List<String>();
 While(str.hasNextLine){
    allText.add(str.nextLine);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to add each line to a separate variable? It is better to add the lines to a list. Then you can access any line as you want.

In JDK 6 or below

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while(reader.ready())
     lines.add(reader.readLine());
```

In JDK 7 or above

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());
```